# two neither in a sentence

Tags: neither-nor

Is the below sentence correct? This is the first time, I am seeing two neither in a sentence.

> In the case of a constitutive relation, **neither** relatum precedes the other temporally, and **neither** can be present without the other.

Comment: I've mainly heard neither...., nor.... . And neither..., neither.... is a new thing I saw here for the first time.

Comment: For more info check this  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either

Comment: @Sina but there is no two 'neither' in a sentence.

Comment: I see. I would write the sentence this way:In the case of a constitutive relation, neither relatum precedes the other temporally, and neither one can be presented without the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to see why you're confused: as a learner you see these two *neither*s and suspect that this is not some sort of *neither ... neither* construction, like *neither ... nor*, which no one has taught you.

But there is no such construction. This is simply two independent clauses joined with *and*; both clauses happen to begin with the quantifier *neither*. Parse it this way:

> In the case of a constitutive relation [two things are true]:
>
> neither relatum precedes the other temporally
>   and
>   neither [relatum] can be present without the other.

*Neither* means "untrue of both of the two following things". In both clauses the two 'things' are the two relata, so the first clause means

> Relatum A does not precede Relatum B temporally AND Relatum B does not precede Relatum A temporally.

In the second clause, *neither* is 'fused' with its head, *relatum*; this clause means

> Relatum A cannot be present without Relatum B AND Relatum B cannot be present without Relatum A.

Comment: Excellent!!! answer. I never thought in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that makes sense. I wouldn't even suggest any alternatives, I believe this is the most natural construction and has the best tone for the content.

Edit:
You could alternatively use the following, but *neither* is really just a negative version of *either* anyway.

> In the case of a constitutive relation, neither relatum precedes the other temporally **nor can either** be present without the other.

"nor" would not be appropriate because we need to make clear that there are two alternatives and that both are needed.

Comment: Are you sure with neither...., neither .... construction?

Comment: Yes I am. It makes a strong point that both parts conditions are necessary. I would perhaps remove the last comma, but either way the sentence is perfectly correct grammatically.

Comment: Could you provide us with a source to explain it more? And is this American English?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a source for this beyond being a native speaker. This is Australian English, which is probably closer to UK English. In [this link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either) you can see some examples of using neither...nor. You'll notice that each part isn't a full idea. The sentence in this question however has full ideas following each *neither*. It's an abstract concept to get the grasp of, but if I heard either my construction or the original one I wouldn't think it was weird.

Comment: @DanielWesleyPorteous Provide the citation that states about this rule.

Comment: @DanielWesleyPorteous  but there is no two 'neither' in a sentence.

Comment: A quick Google search turns up lots of information about it such as the link I posted above or [this](http://thewritepractice.com/how-to-use-either-neither-or-and-nor-correctly/). Be confident that your original sentence is correct. From the perspective of a native speaker I think it's a good sentence for a formal tone.

Comment: I provided that link to demonstrate examples of when to use neither...nor. If you wish, use my other suggestion which is a standard neither...nor construction.